# Override Microsoft HTTPAPI 2.0

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, iis, node.js

I would like to override port 80 that use by IIS, try to stop application server but port 80 still use by Microsoft HTTPAPI 2.0 with pid 4 but cannot find it on task manager, I would like to achieve (IIS, Apache & Node JS) work on port 80, I'm still searching to find advance firewall or port forwarding that detect by uri then pointing to right webserver,

example `mywebsite.com/apache` goes to apache virtual host, `mywebsite.com/iis` goes to iis virtual host, end else iis is default serve but still no clue, having another vm is make sense to me but is there any else way to achieve IIS, Apache, Node JS work on port 80?

- [netstat info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KlZd.png)
- [iis manager status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYfuT.png)

Note: I'm getting info that port 80 is used by Microsoft HTTPAPI 2.0 is from wapplyzer, this is my first post cannot attached more than 2 images.

Comment: done with URL Rewrite in IIS Manager, but next problem is how to make apache and node start in subfolder?

Comment: To help others who have this issue, write out how you resolve the issue with the ports as an Answer and then mark is as the correct answer, then go create a new Question for your next question.

Comment: ok noted, soon after got home i will rewrite about things i've done